# How to change working directory in Julia Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How to change working directory in Julia Jupyter?

I tried and read everything, still have no idea how to do that. It only allows me to select directories under my home `~/` dir. I can't find any button to go up to `/`.

Comment: removing julia-lang tag as I assume that you mean in the notebook server not within a julia kernel session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure once you have started the server you cannot then go up directories, I may be wrong though.

So best thing to do is start the jupyter notebook server somewhere that contains all of the folders you might need -i.e. the root dir if you want to make sure you have access to everything.

You can use the `--notebook-dir` flag for this. Or you can set defaults in the config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try that! :) OMG this is mind blowing, how people using it...

Comment: There are some fairly fundamental reasons why a server can't access directories above its root. And I guess good reasons why people might not want it to. But agreed it can be annoying!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create the config file, using **cmd** :
`jupyter notebook --generate -config`
Then, search for C:\Users\your_username\.jupyter folder ([Search for that folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA4dM.png)), and right click edit the **jupyter_notebook_config.py**.

Then, **Ctrl+F: #c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir =''** . *Note that the quotes are single quotes.* Select your directory you want to have as home for your jupyter, and copy it with Ctrl+C, for example: *C:\Users\username\JuliaProjects*.

Then on that line, paste it like this : **c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:\\Users\\username\\JuliaProjects'**

Make sure to remove **#**, as it is as comment.

Make sure to double slash **\\** on each name of your path.
**Ctrl+S to save** the config.py file !!!

Go back to your **cmd** and run `jupyter notebook.` It should be in your directory of choice. Test it by making a folder and watch your directory from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I use Jupyter Lab and start it from the Julia REPL (1.4) like this:

```
using IJulia
jupyterlab(dir=pwd(), detached=true)
```